# How do we run multiple cases in labVIEW?

Tags: labview

Im working on running traffic lights on four cases by using case structure and Flat-sequence structure. For example, there is green light on first case, and the rest of the three cases should have red light. As soon as the first case approaches to red light, the second case moves towards the green light. All these are controlled by specific time delays. The flat sequence structure is running the traffic lights properly in all the four cases, but, when I insert case structure, it only runs one case and does not activate the other cases. How can i make the VI run all the four cases simultaneously??

Comment: Great! now add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this is an old CLD exam. There should be a wealth of examples available from a quick search. That said, some suggestions: never use a flat-sequence structure. Ever. Instead you need to use some combination of a state machine and subVIs. NI has a prep kit for the CLD (below). Check it out, it’ll show you what a state machine is in LabVIEW and how to take advantage of subVIs.

http://www.ni.com/gate/gb/GB_EKITCLDEXMPRP/US

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Ryan, the information you provided was really helpful. Just wanted you to know, im learning this software and dont have much knowledge of these things as yet, But ill try my best to look up into these sources.

Comment: Definitely. I re-read my post and realize I may have come off a little harsh. That was definitely not my intention. Are you working from a book? I just finished grading 20 or so of these traffic light examples for a class I taught, so if you have any questions as you put together the state machine, ask away.

Comment: Mr Ryan I really appreciate your concern, and I was following what you told me. This is an assignment given to us, and therefore, we weren't taught much to be able to execute this type of question well. That's why there are a lot of queries.I inserted the case structure within the while loop, and i can run the cases individually. How can I make it automatically move from one case to another?? For example, my case one is almost about to return to red light, so how can i make my second case work automatically as soon as case 1 finishes.

Comment: I assume you have some sort of string or enum value wired to the case selector of the case structure from a shift register? Whatever value you put on the right hand side of the shift register will execute the next iteration of the loop. This is how you transition from one state to the next. To transition from one light color to the next, after the timing has expired, put the next state on the shift register.

Comment: yes Mr. Ryan, I did exactly the same way you told me. And now it running perfectly as I presumed it to run. Just want some more advice regarding it. How can I make it more unique?? What other features can i add to it?

Comment: You could expand it to include a left turn signal, or a pedestrian signal. You could also simulate the presence of cars/pedestrians.

Comment: Noted Mr. Ryan. Thank you for the help. Well, i successfully added the features. But due to lack of time, I was not able to introduce more enhancements. But, nevertheless, thank you for the help.